# Count with CSS Animation: Animation works in all Browsers, except on Apple-Devices

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

**Assumed we have this simple piece of CSS animated counter:**

```css
div::after {
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  content: counter(count);
  animation: counter 5s linear forwards;
  counter-reset: count 0;
}

@keyframes counter {
   0% { counter-increment: count 0;    }
  10% { counter-increment: count 8;    }
  20% { counter-increment: count 16;   }
  30% { counter-increment: count 32;   }
  40% { counter-increment: count 64;   }
  50% { counter-increment: count 128;  }
  60% { counter-increment: count 256;  }
  70% { counter-increment: count 512;  }
  80% { counter-increment: count 1024; }
  90% { counter-increment: count 2048; }
 100% { counter-increment: count 4000; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Description of the issue:**

The counter works perfect on Firefox and Chrome browsers, but not on any kind of Apple devices (probably Safari issue?).

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried a javascript version?

Comment: @dalelandry: Thanks for your request! Not yet, I'd prefer a pure CSS solution...

Answer (score 0):

Just change the content from counter to text, i.e.: `content: counter(count);` to `content: '0'`.
And further accordingly in your keyframes: `counter-increment: count 8;` to `content: '8'` etc. Works perfectly in Safari.